# How to change more than one cell background color in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am changing the cell background color of `jan 12` using `dayRender`. How can I change one more cell background color in same month?

```
var data=[{
  'specialDay':'2017-01-12'
}];

console.log(data)

var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    defaultView: 'month',

    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        var today = new Date(data[0].specialDay);
        if (date.getDate() === today.getDate() && date.getMonth() === today.getMonth()) {
            cell.css("background-color", "red");
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/937/

**EDIT** Attempt at using a loop, which still isn't working properly:

```
var data = [{
  'name': 'xxx',
  'specialDay': [{
    'day': '2017-01-12'
  }, {
    'day': '2017-01-19'
  }]
}];
console.log(data)
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  defaultView: 'month',

  dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    $.each(data.specialDay, function(index, element) {
      alert(element.day)
      var today = new Date(data[0].specialDay);
      if (date.getDate() === today.getDate() && date.getMonth() === today.getMonth()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
      }
    })

  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/941/

Comment: by adding more elements to the `data` array and looping through them, I guess? You haven't said how you're defining which other cells you want to change, but I would assume it's going to be using that, otherwise why did you make it an array? Do you know how to loop through an array?

Comment: Definitely need a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: " this is what I have tried to loop through.". What are you referring to as "this" in that statement? There's no loop in your code, nor is there anything to loop through. I can't see any evidence that you've tried this. Also that statement doesn't answer the questions that I asked. If you can answer those, then I can help you.

Comment: @ADyson I am extremely sorry. i forgot to attach fiddle in above comment .http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/941/

Comment: I've added an answer based on that. I've also edited the question to include the updated code from your newer JSFiddle, otherwise the question and answer would not have made sense to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of relatively simple things wrong with your attempt, both of which resulted in errors being displayed in the browser console:

1. I couldn't see any reason for `data` to be an array. SpecialDay within it is an array and that seemed to be sufficient for your purpose. Then in places you were trying to access `data.specialDay`, which didn't exist (it would have had to be `data[0].specialDay` because you had to access the first object of the `data` array, which then contained the `specialDay` property).
2. `new Date(data[0].specialDay);` The date is actually in the `day` property of the object(s) within the `specialDay` array. Putting an array into the Date constructor doesn't make a lot of sense - an array can't be parsed as a date. Ironically, right above it you had alerted `element.day`, which is what you needed to feed into the array, so you weren't far away from the correct solution to this one.

Here's a working version of the code:

```
var data = { //data is now an object
  'name': 'xxx',
  'specialDay': [{
    'day': '2017-11-12'
  }, {
    'day': '2017-11-19'
  }]
};
console.log(data)

var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'month',
  dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    $.each(data.specialDay, function(index, element) {
      //alert(element.day)
      var today = new Date(element.day); //put the correct variable into the Date constructor
      if (date.getDate() === today.getDate() && date.getMonth() === today.getMonth()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
      }
    })

  }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/947/ for a demo.

One other observation: you are using a very old version of fullCalendar (1.6.1) which is no longer supported. The current version is 3.6.2. I would advise you to upgrade as soon as you can. There may be a small number of changes you need to make, including upgrading your jQuery version, including moment.js etc, but it's all clear in the documentation. This link has a guide to upgrading from version 1.x to 2.0 and above: https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/

Comment: Yes you are correct.But I am unable to make alignment changes od dates and events  in latest version.that is why am using old version.

Comment: It should be possible to do exactly what you're doing now, but using the latest fullCalendar. In the particular case of the dayRender callback, the `date` parameter is now a momentJS object instead of a JS Date, so you have to adjust for that, but there shouldn't be any other difficulty AFAIK. If you want to upgrade and have got some errors you don't understand, then post a new question and we can work through them.

Comment: Sure :-):-)Thanks:-)